# Upload file with Symfony 2 and Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, symfony, file-upload

I have reviewed official docs http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html and other topics, but can't find the solution

So, here is my angular action

```
     $scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("file", files[0]);

            $http.put('/api/clients/' + id +'/files', fd, {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
                transformRequest: angular.identity
            }).success(function(resp) {
                    $mdToast.show(
                        $mdToast.simple()
                            .textContent(resp.message)
                            .hideDelay(1500)
                    ); 
            }).error(function(resp) {
                $mdToast.show(
                    $mdToast.simple()
                        .textContent(resp.message)
                        .hideDelay(1500)
                );
            })

        };
```

And my entity for upload files

```
namespace PT\HearingBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Class Client
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PT\HearingBundle\Repository\ClientRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="`client_uploads`")
 *
 * @package PT\HearingBundle\Entity
 * @author Roman Lunin <roman.lunin@primary.technology>
 */
class ClientUploads
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @JMS\Groups("list")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file.")
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/pdf" })
     */
    private $files;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="files")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @JMS\Groups("list")
     *
     * @var Client
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get client
     *
     * @return Client
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    /**
     * Get files
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFiles()
    {
        return $this->files;
    }

    /**
     * Set files
     *
     * @param string $files
     *
     * @return ClientUploads
     */
    public function setFiles($files)
    {
        $this->files = $files;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set client
     *
     * @param int $client
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setClient($client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

It's form

```
class ClientUploadsType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('files')
            ->add('files', FileType::class)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PT\HearingBundle\Entity\ClientUploads'
        ));
    }
}
```

And, well, I can't get what exactly I should put in my symfony controller, now it's looks like that and doesn't working at all.

```
public function putClientFilesAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $upload = new ClientUploads();
        $form = $this->createForm(ClientUploadsType::class, $upload);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

            var_dump($request->files->get('file'));
            exit;

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        if ( ! $form->isValid()) {
            return new JsonResponse(array(
                'message' => 'File is not valid'
            ), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        $file = $upload->getFiles();

        $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();
        $file->move(
            $this->container->getParameter('files_directory'),
            $fileName
        );

        $upload->setClient($id);
        $upload->setFiles($fileName);

        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse(array(
            'message' => 'File saved'
        ), Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

Comment: Your back-end seems okay, did you check your request body and see if the file is there? You might want to see my working implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480635/angular-4-upload-to-symfony-rest-api/52563729#52563729